# Add margin to a subplot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am wondering if it's possible to add margin, i.e., extra spacing, to one out of several subplots.

Imagine having 3 bar charts, I would like to add some extra just between the 1st and the second bar chart but not between the second and third bar chart.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=1)

plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
plt.bar([1,2,3,4], [5,2,4,7])

plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
plt.bar([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4])

plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
plt.bar([1,2,3,4], [3,3,2,3])
```

I've tried to use [`subplots_adjust()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) (as shown above) but it seems to only allow adjusting the spacing for all subplots at once.

Is there a way to introduce extra spacing between just one pair of subplots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use gridspec. You can adjust each subplot separately, examples are in 
https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html